# Javascript, storing a number and retrieving on another html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with a part of my website. 
I need to be able to click on a hyperlink. When the user clicks on this link they will be transferred to an application form page. The reference number (5 digit code that is in the form of a header) needs to be stored and displayed in a text box on the form.

How would I do this? I have gotten the hyperlink to work but been stuck on the next part for a while now.

Comment: Where do you have that ID right now? As a get parameter in the URL?

Comment: Consider looking into the LocalStorage api.

Comment: I have an ID for the header as "adminref"
An ID for the hyperlink as "admin"

I have made a seperate javascript file with

Comment: "use strict";


    function init(){
 var AdminApply = document.getElementById("admin"); 
 var WarehouseApply = document.getElementById("warehouse"); 
 AdminApply.onclick = admin;
 WarehouseApply.onclick = warehouse;
 
    }

    function admin(){
 var adminRef = document.getElementById("adminref").innerHTML;
 localStorage.reference = adminRef;
    }
    function warehouse(){
 var WarehouseRef = 
    document.getElementById("warehouseref").innerHTML;
 localStorage.reference = WarehouseRef;
 
    }

    window.onload = init;

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string parameters to send the ID if it is not something sensitive and can be exposed in the URL. If it is a sensitive ID which you cannot expose to the user, consider using local storage. You can read more about local storage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: localStorage isn't any more secure. The user can still see it in plain text.

Comment: I have tried to use local storage but im not sure if I am doing it correctly

Comment: @IngoBürk it is better than exposing the value in a query string param. It can be encrypted if need be

Comment: @Deano what problem are you facing? are you able to set the value and retrieve it on the same page? ( using localStorage.getItem("key") )

Comment: @SaranshKataria When I click my hyperlink, the reference number (5 digit code) does not display in the text file. I'm not even sure if I am storing the value correctly, although im not getting any errors.

Comment: @Deano what file are you referring to? All you have to do is localStorage.setItem('key', 12345);
Where 12345 is the 5 digit code

Comment: @SaranshKataria
We have two use 2 HTML files and 2 Java files.
One HTML file is a job description, it then has a hyperlink that links to the other HTML file, application form. 
I have to transfer the reference number for the job onto the other HTML page and display it in the "Enter reference number" text box.

Comment: No, it's absolutely not better. Obscurity is no security. We've known this for decades now.